# Write to a textfile and plot with c++ and gnuplot

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gnuplot

I'm quite a novice on C++, I am trying to write the output of my script to a text-file and plot the output using gnuplot. Here is the script:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    double y;
    int N=256;
    double Fs=30000;//sampling frequency
    double  T=1/Fs;//sample time 
    double f=5000;//frequency
    double *in;
    fftw_complex *out;
    double t[N-1];//time vector 
    fftw_plan plan_forward;



    in = (double*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(double) * N);
    out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * N);


    for (int i=0; i< N;i++)
    {
        t[i]=i*T;
        in[i] =0.7 *sin(2*M_PI*f*t[i]);// generate sine waveform
        double multiplier = 0.5 * (1 - cos(2*M_PI*i/(N-1)));//Hanning Window
       in[i] = multiplier * in[i];
      }

    plan_forward = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d ( N, in, out, FFTW_ESTIMATE );

    fftw_execute ( plan_forward );

    for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
    printf ( "  %4d  %12f\n", i, in[i] );
    }

fftw_destroy_plan ( plan_forward );
fftw_free ( in );
fftw_free ( out );
return 0;
}
```

So the outputs are i and in[i]

As the first attmept to write my output to a text file I have added this code to my script inside the main function:

```
fstream myfile;

myfile.open ("example.txt");

  for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)

    { myfile << i << std::endl;

      myfile << in[i] << std::endl;
    }

myfile.close();
```

I could not get i and in[i] in two columns besides each other so I have typed

```
./Nameofthefile >stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt
```

in the terminal and now I have have i and in[i] in two columns side by side in my stdout.txt file something like this:

```
 1      0.000092

 2      0.000368
```

and so on. When I type

```
gnuplot "stdout.txt"
```

in the terminal I get this error:

```
0      0.000000
^
"stdout.txt", line 1: invalid command
```

I have two questions:

1-How to fix this error

2- How to put i and in[i] in two columns side by side in my "example.txt". The way I see it in "stdout.txt". Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your header files are not recommended for `C++`. To use the `C++` versions of the former `C` standard library headers you can specify the name prefixed with `c` and without the `.h` extension.

So these:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
```

would become:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
```

Your problem is that you are not providing everything gnuplot needs to draw a graph. You are supplying the raw data but no instructions on what to do with the data.

You need to output a file something like this:

```
plot '-' using 1:2
1 0.000092
2 0.000368
```

So you can add the plot command in your original program like this:

```
printf("plot '-' using 1:2\n"); // add this
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    printf("%4d  %12f\n", i, in[i]);
}
```

Or in your other example like this:

```
std::fstream myfile;

myfile.open("example.txt");

myfile << "plot '-' using 1:2" << std::endl;
for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    myfile << i << " " << in[i] << std::endl;
}

myfile.close();
```

You can plot the output file using:

```
gnuplot -p < "stdcout.txt"
```

Comment: `<stdlib.h>` etc. are part of the C++ library, there is nothing "wrong" about using them.

Comment: @JonathanWakely It seems you are right, I changed the wording somewhat.

Comment: Thank you , I have changed my script. It does not give me any error but is not producing anything either. Maybe I am missing  a gnuplot library that should be included?

Comment: @MaryE Try using `gnuplit -p "stdout.txt"` otherwise the window dissapears as fast as it arrives. The `-p` makes it persistent.

Comment: Thank you, I did it..still nothing pops out

Comment: @MaryE Have you checked the contents of the text file to make sure it contains something like in the example given in my answer?

Comment: @MaryE  I'm not sure what's going wrong for you then unless you picked up my spelling error in my previous comment. I put `gnuplit` rather than `gnuplot`?

Comment: I have to add that stdout.txt and example.txt are a bit different. There is a space in front of the first column of stdout.txt

Comment: @MaryE In my tests it doesn't make any difference if there is a leading space or not. I have no idea why that example is not working for you.

Comment: @Galik Does it work on your computer? Do you get an output for my code?

Comment: @MaryE I didn't run your code because I don't have the `fftw` library installed. But the output file is definitely working using `gnuplot -p stdcout.txt`. But I **just realised** it acts differently if you specify the filename using quotes! When I ran gnuplot I didn't use quotes. When I use quotes it fails.

Comment: @MaryE The proper way t run the gnuplot is like this: `gnuplot -p < "stdcout.txt"`. I used quotes but its ok because I also used the redirection symbol `<`.

Comment: I have tried it..still nothing pops out...very strange..it reads the column though because when I have only one column in my text file it gives me error about the values.

Comment: @Galik I just googled gnuplot does not show a graph and it turns out I was missing  gnuplot-x11 !!...I am going to accept your answer  because the commands that you taught me are all correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87991/discussion-between-mary-e-and-galik).

Answer (score 1):

You've created a data file for gnuplot.  However, gnuplot expects a script in its own language, which may then use the `plot` command (or similar commands) to actually generate plots of data files.  Read the [gnuplot documentation](http://www.gnuplot.info/documentation.html).

To get two columns, just insert a space between them:

```
myfile << i << " " << in[i] << std::endl;
```

You can also use a tab `"\t"`, which will probably lead to a nicer display when you view the file, but gnuplot does not care which one you use.